# Any set of functions for this new definition of orthogonality?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, orthogonality

The set of functions $\phi_k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are orthonormal iff
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi_m(t)\phi_n^\ast(t)dt=\delta_{mn}.$$
For example $\phi_m(t)=\mbox{sinc}(t-m)$ is an example of a family of orthonormal functions. Now my question is that is there a set of (infinit many) functions, denote them $\phi_i(t)$, such that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi_k(t)\phi_m(t)\phi_\ell^\ast(t)\phi_n^\ast(t)dt=\delta_{km}\delta_{\ell n}?$$

Comment: Is this Kronecker delta or Dirac delta? I know it's likely the first, but it's usually written as $\delta_{mn}$

Comment: Also, is your last expression precisely what you wanted to write, or maybe you wanted $\delta (k-l) \delta (m-n)$ to make it better fit with the original definition?

Comment: @YuriyS It is Kronecker delta function. I will edit it, however, the second one is in this form that I have written since in writing in your way, there will be an ambiguity. Indeed, in that case, the integral is one iff $m=k=l=n$